# How to get body from Mono<ClientResponse>?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor, reactor-netty

I am trying to implement the BodyExtractor interface get the body from Mono< ClientResponse> as an Object instead of it in Mono.
I could not find any example of BodyExtractor implementation. I am wondering is this a good idea to implement it or is there any other way to get the body as an object.

Below is the code line that I currently have

```
 public Mono<ResponseEntity<Mono<JsonNode>>> processUnmappedApiRequest(ServerHttpRequest request, JsonNode body) {
        RequestData reqData = this.prepareReqMetadata(request, body);
        Mono<ClientResponse> response = commonConnector.getApiResponse(reqData);

        return response.map(respData ->  {
            int latestVersion = respData.headers().header("version").size() == 0 ? getLatestVersion(request) :
                    Integer.parseInt(respData.headers().header("version").get(0));
            List converterList;
            if((converterList = converterSequenceProvider.getConverterList(reqData.getRequestPath(), latestVersion, reqData.getVersion())) != null){
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(respData.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class).map(respBody -> convertToDesiredVersion(converterList, respBody)));
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(respData.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class));
        });
    }
```

In this method my return type is Mono< ResponseEntity< Mono< JsonNode>>> and I am trying to convert it to Mono< ResponseEntity< JsonNode>> because my team is not agreeing with Mono inside a Mono.

So the main point here is I don't want to use bodyToMono method and I am not sure how to use body method.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to return just a `Mono` object, you can use the `flatMap` method instead of `map`, so you can avoid something like `Mono<Mono<X>>` and get just `Mono<X>`.

`map`

> Transform the item emitted by this Mono by applying a synchronous
>   function to it.

`flatMap`

> Transform the item emitted by this Mono asynchronously, returning the
>   value emitted by another Mono (possibly changing the value type).

Also, there is a method on `ServerResponse.BodyBuilder` `syncBody` which can take normal body and return it in `Mono`. Map function's argument is already a non wrapped object, so you can do something like:

```
JsonNode jsonNode=transform(clientResponse);
return ResponseEntity.ok().syncbody(jsonNode);
```

Comment: I am glad it's working, would you please accept this answer ?